# How should I read files in C++ w/ SDL?

Tags: c++, file, sdl

I have tried looking for tutorials and reading the docs but there's almost no information on how to use SDL to read and write to text files, etc. So, would it be a better idea to just use regular C++?

Comment: Unless you define what you mean with "good", you are just asking for opinions, making your question off-topic. Even if you did, please make sure you first show some effort yourself assessing the situation.

Comment: Well, I meant I was looking for the better option. Are they both virtually similar or are there benefits of one over the other?

Comment: Whatever gets the job done (file into memory) would seem to me to be "good enough". Why would the solution have to use one library or another? In the end it's just bytes in memory;  so whatever works ;)

Comment: Thanks, some of the SDL docs are pretty scarce.

Comment: Think about it the different way: Why would SDL offer anything built into its C base (making it available in C++, too)?

Answer (score 0):

While SDL have [RWops](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RWops), its API is exactly the same as stdlib fread/fwrite/fseek. It serves different purpose though. There may be (and, as SDL is game oriented, very often are) cases when data processing code don't really care where data coming from (regular file, byte array in memory, zip or any other form of archive, network source, or even procedural generator). If this code uses RWops-like abstraction you can just write a new implementation for it and it and it will work without any modification or recompilation. SDL itself and all SDL-based libraries like SDL_image, SDL_ttf, etc. support loading data from RWops, as well as a few 'standard' RWops implementations like `SDL_RWFromFile` or `SDL_RWFromMem`.

If question is "what you should use", then there is really no answer, as there is no 'better' here. If you're writing a library though, it is very reasonable to provide a way for calling side to redefine what 'file' is (or at least load data from memory array).